# How to update matches on Challonge with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to update a match score on Challonge with PHP. I'm not sure on how to send the scores and winner ID. Here is the [API page](http://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/matches/update):

*Do I need to make an array for the CSV scores and Winner ID?*

This is the current URL I am trying to use:

```
https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/3k8drpj2/matches/36463543.json?api_key=&scores_csv=3-1&winner_id=24899488
```

Thanks

Comment: No, you don't need an array, just a comma separated string i.e.: `1-3,3-0,3-2` . Have you tried to send the request already? if so, what was the response ?

Comment: Tried the request, this is the result:http://pastebin.com/dPE6dVDh

Comment: can you post the full request url  without the apikey ?

Comment: I'll go put it in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/2S67FN7s

Comment: You should paste here instead of pastebin.com.

Comment: The response request shows 2 matches ids `"prerequisite_match_ids_csv":"36463541,36463542"` but you're only posting 1 result `3-1`, is this normal ?

Comment: I think you should update your question with the full request url and response so other users can also  help you.